# Scenekit Xcode Template ( BoilerPlate) code crashes in runtime, Xcode 13, 2021

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, xcode13

I have started to learn Scenekit, The starting template code in Xcode for Game app crashes during runtime on simulator.I have set deployment target as iOS 15. I have attached screenshots below,

[image: The Crashed Line of code]

[image: Folder layout]

The Folder layout is shown above.

Most tutorial shows the first run successful.

*I'm using MacBook Air, i5*

**Update 1:**

The asset Ship is also present in folder
[image]

Comment: I don't see the same issue.

Comment: yeah, I don't know why. Is it some kind of bug in Xcode 13!!

Comment: I tried ***guard let myScene = SCNScene(named: "MyScene") 
    else { fatalError("Unable to load scene file.") }*** But still Not works

Comment: @Vivek: can you check, if the "ship.scn" is really inside your "art.scnassets" folder?

Comment: Yeah, Its there. I have added file folder screen shot too. Its the default template code.

Comment: Wait, does MacBook Air come with a new M1 chip or whatever it's called?

Comment: Nope, its the old one 1.8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5

Comment: It will be great if you upvote this question, as it pops in front of more Users... ;)

Comment: installed Version 12.5 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with Xcode 12.5 and iPhone 14.5, this crash didn't occur, may be in higher Xcode version and OS produces it.

If it occurs to other developers, could be bug from Apple in latest OS & version.

Just try with lowest version for time being if you want to just ignore crash .

Comment: Same problem for me Xcode 13.2.1, both for iOS 14 and 15 targets. I also get the "warning" 

Could not find bundle inside /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
scntool

this is probably related. I'll try the 12.5.1 version, iOS 14 should be enough to update my app.